# How can I use css to make this?

Tags: html, css, colors, ellipse

[image]

I suspect using line gradient?I know how to do the ellipse thing but I just don't understand how I can make the red line right through the middle?

Comment: i would create an aboulste span element, and place the text over it, then give that span element all the CSS needed for the line effect

Comment: I thought of that but isn't loading image slower? x.x than css

Answer (score 1):

I would make something like this: **[DEMO FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/t2ofpxru/2/)**

CSS:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    background-color:black;
    z-index:-2;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align:center;
}
#line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 80%;
    left:10%;
    height: 1px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px 5px red;
    z-index:-1;
    background-color: red;
}

#text{
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
letter-spacing:8px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="text">Text</div>
    <div id="line"></div>
</div>
```